# If $a, b, c$ are in geometric progression and $\log a -\log 2b, \log 2b -\log 3c, \log 3c-\log a$ are in AP.

Tags: triangles

> If $a, b, c$ are in geometric progression and $\log a -\log 2b, \log 2b -\log 3c, \log 3c-\log a$ are in AP. Find the type of the triangle, if it’s sides are $a, b, c$

From the given data

$$b^2=ac$$ and 
$$2(\log 2b-\log 3c)=\log 3c-\log a +\log a -\log 2b$$

$$\log 2b=\log 3c$$
$$2b=3c$$

How does this tell us the type of the triangle? The relations between the sides is $$2b=3c$$and $$4a=9c$$

$$2b=3c=\frac{4a}{3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG $\dfrac cb=\dfrac ba=r, b=ar; c=ar^2$

$$\log a-\log2b=\log\dfrac a{2b}=\log\dfrac1{2r}$$

Similarly, $$\log2b-\log3c=\cdots=\log\dfrac{2}{3r}$$

$$\log3c-\log a=\cdots=\log(3r^2)$$

$$\implies\log\dfrac1{2r}+\log(3r^2)=2\cdot\log\dfrac{2}{3r}$$

$$\dfrac{3r^2}{2r}=\left(\dfrac{2}{3r}\right)^2\implies r=\dfrac23$$  as $r$ is real

Now use  [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to find whether it has an obtuse or a right angle

Comment: I think the answer key has a problem here, but I got an acute triangle (taking $\frac{2a}{3}$ to be the largest side). The given answer is obtuse. Could you please verify this?

Answer (score 0):

$a^2+b^2 = a^2 + (2\cdot\frac{3}{4} a)^2 = \frac{13}{4}a^2$ while $c^2 = (\frac{4}{9}a)^2 = \frac{16}{81}a^2$. Since $a^2+b^2 > c^2$, the triangle is acute from the Pythagorean inequality theorem.

---

Note:
This inequality does not necessarily come from the cosine rule: a triangle can be continuously deformed from an acute triangle to a right triangle, and then to an obtuse triangle. Since $a^2+b^2 \ne c^2$ in this problem, the triangle must be either acute or obtuse.

When $a=b=c=1$, we have an acute, equilateral triangle, but $1^2+1^2 > 1^2$, so when $a^2+b^2 > c^2$ the triangle must be acute. See more on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201638/is-there-any-way-to-judge-if-a-triangle-is-acute-or-obtuse/201640#201640).

Comment: For all you know, $a$ could have been $b$, $b$ could have been $a$. What I'm implying is shouldn't we check all 3 choose 2 combinations of sums for given $a, b$ and $c$?